# What is needed to justify taking the derivative of a geometric series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Of course, if $|p| < 1$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p^n=\dfrac{1}{1-p}\text{.}$$
One fact that is particularly useful in probability and financial mathematics is taking the derivative of both sides leads to 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}np^{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{(1-p)^2}\text{.}$$
What is needed to justify doing this?

I was reading the Real Analysis text by Bartle yesterday, and my recollection is that if $(f_n) \to f$ converges at some $x \in S$, $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ bounded, 
and if $(f^{\prime}_n) \to g$ uniformly, then $(f_n) \to f$ uniformly and $f^{\prime} = g$ (I imagine this is true only over $S$).

Define $f_n: (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(p) = p^n$. Obviously, $(f_n) \to 0$... oh wait, I realized I'm not working with a *sequence of functions*, but a series (as I'm typing this). So my method is likely invalid.

I'm not asking for a complete answer (go ahead and give one if you'd like), but a list of theorems or a sketch that would assist in proving this problem. This is not homework.

Comment: Look up "power series" and "disc of convergence."

Comment: As you've stated, termwise differentiation is allowed when the sequence of functions **and** the sequence of the derivatives of the functions converge uniformly (this is one sufficient condition, though I think with some small extra assumptions you can get away with less). While you do have a series, you can form the sequence

$$f_n: (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad f_n(p) = \sum_{k = 0}^n p^n$$

And then $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions that satisfies your condition in an appropriate domain (like a strict subset of $[0, 1)$).

Comment: @Clarinetist: Things are more straightforward with power series than with arbitrary sequences/series of differentiable functions. You can find direct proofs for power series (see, for example, Spivak).

Comment: The issue is bringing the derivative inside the infinite sum, i.e. you are exchanging two limit processes and must justify why you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix $k$ and consider series of the form
$$f_k(p)=\sum_{n=0}^kp^n=\frac{1-p^{k+1}}{1-p}$$
Then $f_k$ is differentiable and
$$f_k'(p)=\sum_{n=1}^knp^{n-1}\tag{$*$}$$

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty np^{n-1}$ converges uniformly on sets of the form $\left\{p:|p|\leq r\right\}$, where $r<1$ by Weierstrass' test, or you can simply use the last term in $(*)$ above to obtain the same.

By by the result you stated, the limit function $f(p)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n=\frac{1}{1-p}$ is differentiable on sets of the form $\left\{p:|p|\leq r\right\}$ for $r<1$, and so it is differentiable on $\left\{p:|p|<1\right\}$. From usual calculus and by comparing it with ($*$),
$$\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}=f'(p)=\lim_k f_k'(p)=\lim_k\sum_{n=0}^knp^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty np^{n-1}$$

Comment: You forgot to do the chain rule (have to multiply by the derivative of $1-p$, which "cancels" out with that negative).

Answer (score 2):

**In general**

Let $f_n:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence of differentiable functions s.t.

1) $(f_n)_n$ converge pointwise to $f$,

2) $(f_n')_n$ converge uniformly to $g$.

Then $f'=g$, i.e.
$$\left(\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)\right)'=\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n'(x).$$

In other word, you can permute the limit and derivative.

---

**On your problem**

We suppose that the convergence radius of the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
is $\mathcal R$. By a theorem of your course, you know that the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$ is also $\mathcal R$. Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_nx^n$. By an other theorem of your course, $f_n$ converge uniformly on all compact $K\subset ]-\mathcal R,\mathcal R[$, and $f_n'$ also. Therefore, for all $|x|<\mathcal R$, you have that $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)'=\left(\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)'=\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_nx^n\right)'=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=1}^nna_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}.$$

---

**Conclusion**

You can always differentiate series terms by terms when $|x|<\mathcal R.$

Comment: Can you explain why $f^{\prime}_n$ must be uniformly convergent?

Comment: Just a **Hint** : $f_n(x)=\int f_n'(x)\mathrm d x$. Since $f'_n$ converge uniformly you can permute limit and integral. If the convergence of $(f_n')$ is not uniform, it will not work. Example $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}e^{-nx}$ when $x\in [0,1]$. You have that $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=0$ but $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n'(0)=-1\neq 0=\left(\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(0)\right)'.$$.@Clarinetist