# Is there a name for the infinite series: $1+2x+3x^2+\dots$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, terminology

The infinite series $S=1+2x+3x^2+\dots$ can be evaluated using a recurrence:
\begin{align}
S&=1+2x+3x^2+\dots\\
&=(1+x+x^2+\dots)+(x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots)\\
&=(1+x+x^2+\dots)+x(1+2x+3x^2+\dots)\\
&=(1+x+x^2+\dots)+xS
\end{align}

The first infinite sum is a geometric series, so it converges to $\frac1{1-x}$. Rewriting all, I have:
\begin{align}
S&=\frac1{1-x}+xS\\
S(1-x)&=\frac1{1-x}\\
S&=\frac1{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}

**Question**: Does this series have any particular name?

Comment: Don't know that it has any particular name, but that's the derivative of the geometric series. See for example [What is needed to justify taking the derivative of a geometric series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926814/what-is-needed-to-justify-taking-the-derivative-of-a-geometric-series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ belongs to a class of series called arithmetico-geometric series, which are the sums of [arithmetico-geometric sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

These in turn are a class within the more general series known as power series.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, whenever $|x| < 1$, the proposed series converges and equals the derivative of the geometric power series. This is as far as I can tell.